# Obtener una columna de varios elementos Firebase Database

Tags: java, firebase

estoy programando una aplicación en Android Studio, implementando una Database de Firebase.

El problema reside cuando trato de obtener solamente cada mensaje (columna "msg") en toda la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De acuerdo, la intención es coger todos los "msg" y listarlos en una RecyclerView, pero no sé cómo puedo obtener el "msg" de cada mensaje.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con el código anterior logro obtener los campos de solamente un mensaje, pero no sé cómo abarcar todos los existentes.

El resultado con dicho código es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo que puedo listar solamente los mensajes que indique en el código y no recorrer toda la tabla. ¿Alguien puede decirme cómo recopilo todos? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Tendrías que recorrer todos los hijos de `Chats` y buscar en ellos el valor de la clave `msg` o hacer otro tipo de búsqueda. De todos modos me parece un error lo que quieres hacer. Firebase computa por la cantidad de lecturas que haces en los documentos, si tienes un millón de documentos tal código te va a computar, por cada persona que lo use, un millón de lecturas. Si estás en un plan de pago te espera la cárcel uno de estos meses y si es un plan gratuito, Firebase se bloquea por el resto del mes cuando excedes los límites. O sea, si el día 3 te pasas de los límites, la App estará caída...

Comment: ...casi todo un mes. Otro problema en tu caso es que para obtener los `msg` tendrás que traer a memoria todo el nodo y Firebase computa también por ancho de banda. En tu caso, si la App se usa mucho generará una factura jugosa.  Lee la documentación de Firebase sobre la forma de montar tu estructura de datos. Evalúa las necesidades de tu App y en base a eso monta la estructura de datos. Si necesitas todos los mensajes del modo que indicas tendrás que pensar en un modelo de datos en el cual no tengas que leer tooooodos  los nodos de toooodos los usuarios para leer todos los mensajes.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes buscar un dato concreto con `orderByChild()` y `equalTo()`.
En tu caso podrías probar con:

```
chef.orderByChild("msg").equalTo("hola").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
```